# Raycaster / Touch not registering on mobile w/ THREE.DragControls

Tags: javascript, mobile, three.js, drag-and-drop, device-orientation

I have made a .JSON object into a hyperlink by using 3Dink.js, it works fine on desktop but on mobile I have to tap the object many times before it eventually registers.

My code loads a .json object and adds the link to it via 3Dink, it also contains a listener for mobile vs. desktop to set the controls.

The feature works perfectly on desktop using only 3Dink, and on mobile it works when the touch eventually registers. Does anyone know what might be causing it to not register right away?

3Dink: http://3dink.webcrow.jp/reference/2.1.0.html

I have tried setting up a raycaster with a window.open call but it does not register either.

```
        var dragControls = new THREE.DragControls(objects, camera, renderer.domElement);
        dragControls.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
            dragControls.enabled = true;
        });
        dragControls.addEventListener('touchend', function() {
            dragControls.enabled = false;
        });



        stats = new Stats();
        container.appendChild(stats.dom);

        window.mobilecheck = function() {
            var check = false;
            (function(a) {
                if (
                    /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i
                    .test(a) ||
                    /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i
                    .test(a.substr(0, 4))) check = true;
            })(navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera);
            return check;
        };

        if (window.mobilecheck() == true) {
            controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(camera, THREE.WebGLRenderer);
        } else {
            controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
            controls.minPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2 - 0.2;
            controls.maxPolarAngle = Math.PI / 2 + 0.2;
            dragControls.addEventListener('dragstart', function() {
                controls.enabled = false;
            });
            dragControls.addEventListener('dragend', function() {
                controls.enabled = true;
            });

            //controls.enablePan = false;
            //controls.enableZoom = false;
        };

        var geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
        var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
        var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial();

        //wevhead
        loader.load('models/wevhead.json', handle_load1);

        function handle_load1(geometry, materials) {
            var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial(materials);
            material.morphTargets = true;

            wevhead = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
            scene.add(wevhead);

            DDDINK.addURL(wevhead, "https://distrokid.com/hyperfollow/wev/gbMx");
            DDDINK.domEvent.setGlobalLinkConfig('_self', 'ON', 'ON', 0xffffff);
            DDDINK.readRendererObj(renderer, scene, camera, );
            DDDINK.domEvent.addFnc('Fn', 'A');

            //wevhead.rotation.y = 3.14;
            wevhead.position.y = -10;
            wevhead.position.z = -8;
            wevhead.scale.set(3, 3, 3);

            //wevhead.rotation.x = 0.4;
        }
        wevhead = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

///later in the code

```
    function onTouchStart(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        mouse.x = (event.pageX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = -(event.pageY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;

        // find intersections
        raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

        var headintersect = raycaster.intersectObject(wevhead);
        var link1 = 'https://distrokid.com/hyperfollow/wev/gbMx'
        if (headintersect.length > 0) {
            window.open(link1);
        }
```

3Dink has worked for me using Device Orientation Controls before, I think something about DragControls.js is interfering with it's ability to recognize the tap.